# Does the Constant Timer added in my HTTP Request affect the results in the Summary Report?

Tags: jmeter

I have a HTTP Request in my Thread Grpup that takes around 20 to 30 seconds to complete with a single user, so when I added 50 users I get a 500/Internal Server Error or 503/Server has been shutdown sometimes.

I want to add a Constant Timer with 40 seconds (in miliseconds) under the HTTP Request so maybe the application will have some time to process it. I am going to the rigth way?

If I add the Constant Timer will it be calculate as well in the Summary Report?

I need that the Jmeter give the time to the API (My aplication) complete the process (need at least 30 seconds) and it may be or not affetct my Summary Report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PreProcessors, Post-Processors and Timers are not counted in the Elapsed time. so response time will not be impacted.

However Throughout (the number of requests for the test duration) will be lower.

See [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for more information on the above metrics.

With regards to "right way" - real users don't "hammer" application non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations so if you're simulating a real user you should have non-zero think time, however 40 seconds it kind of too much for me. Take a look at [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for more tips on properly configuring your JMeter test.